# Example of live site with trusted, signed but revoked certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, revoked

I'm drawing up some documentation for users with the intent on educating them on certificate revocation. I would like to include screen shots of browsers to demonstrate the user experience when encountering a revoked cert. The revocation can occur via either OCSP or CRL.

I've tried digging around CRLs, but they list the serial number of a certificate and don't provide a URL for me to try connecting.

Could someone provide a URL to a live site with a non-self-signed but revoked cert? Or perhaps there's a way to look up certs in a CRL and cross reference them to a URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this one fit the bill?  https://test-sspev.verisign.com:2443/test-SSPEV-revoked-verisign.html

Comment: That will fit the bill! Thanks. Although there's a funny port number assigned to the URL, the user experience should be the same, allowing for good documentation with screenshots of what users will encounter with Firefox, Safari, IE, etc.

Comment: Note that this is an EV certificate.  Some browsers check revocation lists for EV certs but not for non-EV certs.  It would be good to have one that wasn't an EV cert to also test with.  See e.g. http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2013/05/13/how-certificate-revocation-doesnt-work-in-practice.html

Comment: The certificate for this site is now expired :(

Comment: `test-sspev.verisign.com` hostname doesn't resolve in DNS

Answer (score 18):

Here's a second in case anyone else stumbles upon this question (my company firewall blocks port 2443 outbound):

https://revoked.grc.com/

EDIT: This is a VERY belated update, but I just discovered:

https://badssl.com/

Which, at least for me, has everything I needed to test.

Comment: I wanted to see, how curl command works for self signed certificate. https://self-signed.badssl.com/ helped me in understanding the same.

Answer (score 5):

The [DigiCert Trusted Root Authority Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm) page contains links to hosts with revoked certificates (look for the text “Demo Sites for Root” on that page).

You can find a revoked EV certificate under *DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA → Demo Sites for Root → Revoked*.

Answer (score 0):

List of testing web pages with valid, expired or revoked TLS certificates: https://crt.sh/test-websites